# Keyword description in navigation text field path

Tags: dxa, dxa-2.0

We are using DXA 2.0 and Taxonomy based navigation. We would like to use the description field of the site navigation Keyword for the page title. We have added site navigation Category as Metadata field in the Component.

Is it possible to add Keyword description in the list of "Navigation Text Field Paths (NavigationTextFieldPaths)" field in "Navigation Configuration" Component?

Answer (score 3):

The “Navigation Configuration” Component is only used for static, SG-based Navigation.

However, you can create your own Page Model (a subclass of `PageModel`) with a property of type `KeywordModel` and  use standard semantic mapping to map the CM Page’s Keyword field to this property.

The `KeywordModel` property will give you access to the Keyword’s desription and your Page View can use this to set the HTML title.